# Bluetooth is connected to the Headset but Sound output is through the speakers

Tags: apt, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, bluez

I am new user of ubuntu,
I was trying to manually reinstall bluetooth services as headset sound used to stop for 2-3 second every 10-20 min;

I used the following command

```
$ sudo apt-get purge blueman bluez-utils bluez bluetooth && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean
```

and to install I used the following command

```
$ sudo apt install bluez
```

after running this command bluetooth started to work but there was no audio in the headset instead it played the audio through the speaker and Yes i can control the play and pause with the headset

Comment: Did you check under Settings >> Sound the Output is set to your Bluetooth device? If it is set to Speakers, you may try changing that using the dropdown. If your bluetooth is not in the list, please let us know.

Comment: @ArjunKShibu Yes I did checked it,Bluetooth device is not on the list